# Polynomial Long Division explanation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The wikipedia example of [Polynomial Long Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) starts with:

> Divide the first term of the numerator
>   by the highest term of the denominator

if the denominator is $x-3$, and we don't know $x$, how to know which is highest? $x$ or $3$?

Comment: "Highest term" means highest degree term. Polynomial long division is analogous to long division of integers in radix representation.

Comment: Also: the $x$ in a polynomial does not represent an unknown number.

Comment: Arturo: But in fact $\rm\:x\:$ does represent an "unknown number". More precisely it represents a universal (generic) $\rm\:R$-algebra element. $\rm\ R[x]$ is defined so that the equations true in it are precisely those ring-theoretic equations that hold true in every $\rm\ R$-algebra. Therefore an equation is true in $\rm\:R[x]\:$ iff it is a universal identity of $\rm\:R$-algebras. For example see my post [here](http://bit.ly/h7Q81Y) and [see here](http://bit.ly/hUZWoP) and [see here](http://bit.ly/hynx03).

Comment: Maybe we could improve the wikipedia article on Polynomial Long Division then? I wonder if others have been similarly confused.

Comment: @David Kohler: +1 great idea. I did little bit, but it can still be improved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"highest" here means not "greatest", but the one with the highest power of $x$ (which in this case is $x$).

Comment: that is, the "highest-degree" term